# where to put tags.py in django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, tags

I want to use a tag in django.

So I created `project/main_appname/templatetags.`

Then I added `__init__.py` and `active.py`  to it.

However, when I use `{% load active %}` in my template html, the error information is

```
active' is not a valid tag library: Template library active not found, tried  django.templatetags.active,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.active
```

What's wrong with my settings?

Comment: Is `main_appname` installed?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem, after adding main_appname to Installed, I can finally load the tags

Answer (score 0):

You should have a module-wide [register variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) that's an instance of `django.template.Library`, and you should then [register](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag) the tag to that library for it to be available in your templates. Also be sure that `main_appname` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.tag
def my_tag(...):
```